# Ruby on rails, pass an argument from one action to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two actions in my controller:search, show_db.

say, they look like this:

```
def search
   @uploads=current_user.uploads    
end

def show_db
end
```

I need to pass arguments (@uploads) from `search`-action to `show_db`-action. (I know I could write `@uploads=current_user.uploads` in `show_db`, but I cannot, it is much more complex.)
smt like this:

```
def search
       @uploads=current_user.uploads
       show_db(@uploads)    
end

def show_db(list)
   blablabla
end
```

Is it possible to do?=)

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: you shoulf tell us why you cant instance upload in the show_db action

Comment: it is too complex and it doesnt play a role in dealing with a problem I faced above. I just need to know if passing an argument from one action to another is possible or not.

Comment: Yes, call it with the parameter like any other Ruby method. But it's an instance variable, so you don't even need to.

Comment: @Dave, if you do that, the wrong view will be rendered.

Comment: @cmaitchison By itself that sentence makes no sense-how do you know which view is the "right" one, which solution do you believe is wrong, and huh?

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was assuming that you want the show_db view rendered when you call show_db from search (otherwise why call it?), calling show_db as a method from search will still render the search view unless there is an explicit render 'show_db'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass the result of one method to another it's pretty simple in Ruby, your second code block should work, you just need to use the list variable from the parameter in your method

```
def show_db(list)
  x = list
  list.do_somethings
  etc
end
```

Comment: And it doesnt matter if the methods are in a controller?

Comment: Broadly speaking, no.  Having said that if you are creating a very complex set of methods, you're probably gonna want to rip it out into its own class or module.

Answer (score 0):

Create a third method that knows how to create @uploads, use it from both actions.

Also, if in your index action you want to render show_db with @uploads variable, you can do this:

```
def search
  @uploads=current_user.uploads
  if something
    return show_db(@uploads)
  end
end

def show_db(list)
  blah
  render 'show_db'
end
```

But in this case, show_db is just a method, not a controller action.

Comment: I need it as a controller action as well

Comment: What you are asking cannot be done sensibly, I definitely recommend just extracting common logic from the two controller actions into non-action methods.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use a variable across actions. You should know that each time you make a request from browser, you are creating a new instance of controller. Hence, your variables would not work as they should because you will actually be trying to access an instance variable across instances. An impossible task. 
I suggest using sessions to store information across multiple requests.
Google up how to use sessions.